# Read FILE.txt, then extract part between two lines using Python

Tags: python

I have a FILE.txt file, which contains around 3000 lines.
I wanted to extract several lines (A TABLE that contains 10 columns). So that I can subsequently draw a graph which shows these results in the table

- I tried with this simple code but an error is generated "**SyntaxError: invalid syntax**"

FILE.txt

```
            |  Sim. Time |  t_SCF | t_Grad |     Temp |     E_Kin |
       Step |       [fs] |    [s] |    [s] |      [K] | [Hartree] |
------------|------------|--------|--------|----------|-----------|
          0          0.0    103.5              300.00    0.065553
          1          1.0     87.5     26.7     292.77    0.063973
          2          2.0     89.5     25.6     274.46    0.059971
       1996       1996.0     93.1     24.7     315.92    0.222478
       1997       1997.0     91.8     24.9     312.40    0.068263  
       1998       1998.0    103.1     24.9     310.47    0.067841 
       1999       1999.0     97.7     25.6     310.42    0.067830 
       2000       2000.0     98.4     24.8     309.65    0.067661 
------------|------------|--------|--------|----------|-----------|
            |  Sim. Time |  t_SCF | t_Grad |     Temp |     E_Kin |
       Step |       [fs] |    [s] |    [s] |      [K] | [Hartree] |
```

my script:

```
with open('FILE.txt', 'rb') as f:
     textfile_temp = f.read()

     print textfile_temp.split('------------|------------|--------|--------|----------|-----------|')[1].split("------------|------------|--------|--------|----------|-----------|")[0]
```

Comment: You need parentheses around the argument to `print`, and you can't split a second time on the same string (you already have the result after the first split).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just go with a simple state machine. (Note `'r'` mode instead of `'rb'`!)

```
with open('FILE.txt', 'r') as f:
    in_block = False
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("------------"):
            if in_block:  # trailing separator, we can stop here
                break
            in_block = True
            continue
        if in_block:
            print(line.split())
```

This prints out

```
['0', '0.0', '103.5', '300.00', '0.065553']
['1', '1.0', '87.5', '26.7', '292.77', '0.063973']
['2', '2.0', '89.5', '25.6', '274.46', '0.059971']
['1996', '1996.0', '93.1', '24.7', '315.92', '0.222478']
['1997', '1997.0', '91.8', '24.9', '312.40', '0.068263']
['1998', '1998.0', '103.1', '24.9', '310.47', '0.067841']
['1999', '1999.0', '97.7', '25.6', '310.42', '0.067830']
['2000', '2000.0', '98.4', '24.8', '309.65', '0.067661']
```

for your data.

Comment: Thank you dear AKX
I tried but I got an error; NameError: name 'in_file' is not defined

Comment: Fixed – that was supposed to be `f`.

Comment: Can I retrieve columns to draw a graph?

Comment: Of course you can, but doing that is out of scope for this question. However, getting from a list-of-lists-of-numbers to a chart isn't very difficult.